# c support in mobile platforms

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, webos

Is C a language that can be used on Android, BlackBerry, iPhone, Windows Mobile, and WebOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link may help you [Mobile Development Platform Comparison Matrix](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/45208/1763)

Sort Description as follows:

**Android:**
• Android SDK

• Android Development Tools (ADT) plugin on Eclipse 3.4 and 3.5

*Languages:*

• Java for native apps

• Android Native Development Kit (NDK) for apps requiring C/C++ libraries

*Cost:*
Free, open source; no upfront fees

**iPhone**
• iPhone SDK

• Ansca Corona

• Appcelerator Titanium Mobile

• Nitobi PhoneGap

• Rhomobile Rhodes

• iUI

• DragonFireSDK

• Unity

*Laguages:*

• Objective-C

• HTML, CSS and JavaScript

*Cost:*

• $99 per year for Apple iPhone Developer Program

• Most developer tools are free, open source, others vary from $99 to $400 per year

Comment: (Note, I am not flagging this yet since it has the key answer, but...) While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.